# xamarin binding jar type error

Tags: android, xamarin, binding

I have a library .jar with the following function:

```
public void doAction(ArrayList<String[][]> list, int[] time) { }
```

I have create a binding project and the api.xml has this code:

```
<method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="doAction" native="false" return="void" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
<parameter name="p0" type="java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[][]>">
</parameter>
<parameter name="p1" type="int[]">
</parameter>
</method>
```

I have added the reference of the binding dll in my android project and exploring dll i see:

```
using Android.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Register ("doAction", "(Ljava/util/ArrayList;[I)V", "GetDoAction_Ljava_util_ArrayList_arrayIHandler")]
public virtual void DoAction (IList<string[][]> p0, int[] p1);
```

The usage:

```
var myList = new List<string [] []> ();
var myCmd = new string [5] [];
int [] exeTime = new int [100];

myCmd = new string [5] [];
myCmd [0] = new string [] { "F", "2" };
myCmd [1] = new string [] { "A", "2" };
myCmd [2] = new string [] { "P", "0" };
myCmd [3] = new string [] { "V", "5" };
myCmd [4] = new string [] { "E", "1" };

myList.Add (myCmd);
exeTime [0] = 10;

mLib.DoAction (myList, exeTime);
```

So there is the following error :
mono.android.runtime.JavaObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String[][]

What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. In my case i have next java method:

```
public int addNotes(long modelId, long deckId, List<String[]> fieldsList, List<Set<String>> tagsList)
```

In my binding library it became:

```
public int AddNotes(long p0, long p1, IList<string[]> p2, IList<ICollection<string>> p3);
```

I Solved by changing type of parameter in binding library from string[] to Java.Lang.Object by adding attr rule in Metadata.xml. In my case rule was (in path attribute you need XPath to parameter in api.xml):

```html
<attr path="/api/package[2]/class[1]/method[6]//parameter[3]" name="type">java.util.List&lt;java.lang.Object&gt;</attr>
```